# Stop keyboard and mouse waking up my PC

Tags: windows, windows-10, powercfg

I'm trying to stop my keyboard, mouse and surface pen from waking up my surface pro 6. I ran

```
powercfg /devicequery wake_armed
```

I got 'NONE' as result.

I ran

```
powercfg /devicequery wake_from_any
```

A list showed up, Surface Pen is one of them.

After few hours of researching online I tried the following:

Use Surface Pen as an example

1. Device Manager -> Surface Pen -> Power Management

No Power Management tab

2. CMD -> Run as Administrator -> powercfg /devicedisablewake “Surface Pen”

It shows 'You do not have permission to enable or disable device wake.' However, I have ran it as Administrator with an Administrator account.

3. BIOS -> power management settings

no such setting in my BIOS

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You do not have permission to enable or disable device wake

A solution that worked for me:

1. Enable '*Show hidden devices*' in Device Manager.
2. Check for existing duplicates under '*HID Keyboard Device*' & '*HID compliant mouse*'.
3. The high-lighted entries (devices) are valid and in use, hence they should NOT be uninstalled.
   Duplicates are greyed-out and CAN be uninstalled [right click → *Uninstall*].
4. After uninstalling the duplicates, close the Device Manager.
5. Repeat the Enable or Disable Device Wake commands.